# Partitioning the ASP.NET cache

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

We use the ASP.NET cache to store data throughout the application. Now I want to cache product-specific data and would like to create a sub-partition to avoid key name collision.

For example a key can have a string value in the main cache but I want to have a subset where that key's value is a product object.

I've thought of just inserting a Dictionary into the cache but I'm concerned about thread safety.

Is there a "proper" way of doing this?

Comment: can't you just manage this with key prefixes/suffixes?

Comment: Nope... Hove to be able to iterate over the collection etc, which makes prefixes cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the [Enterprise Library Caching Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649918.aspx) which has an option of creating [CacheManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.caching.icachemanager.aspx) objects built in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could an instance of the [MemoryCache class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.memorycache.aspx) for each partition.